# Drupal 6 not playing nice with jquery 1.11.1

Tags: javascript

I am trying to incorperate a sequential fadIn of several img using a simple Jquery script

```
     $(document).ready(function(){       
$(".fadeInCopy").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(900*index).fadeIn("900");
});
 });
```

I have the jquery loading properly and no errors in the javascript panel. However, the script will not reveal the elements. I have this working on a test page but once I install in Druapl 6 it does not respond. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would comment this, but I'm new to drupal stack exchange. Try wrapping this method around your javascript/jquery:

```
(function ($){
   $(document).ready(function(){
      //code here
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Sometimes the $ symbol alias for jQuery causes conflict.

Or you can replace all $ symbols with jQuery and see if that works.